# Microservices with Spring boot, Message queue, Node.js and Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, spring-boot, rabbitmq, microservices

So hey guys!

I just got a complex exercise and I really don't now where to begin, I was hoping someone would point me in the right direction! :)

[Exercise description here (cant embed images yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQqf5.png)

If anyone could point me to relevant guides or where to start from that would be awesome!

I have worked with Angular and Node/Spring API's but nothing to this extent so all help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if there is no specific order, I would go like that:

1. Create a Spring boot project for **Voting** Micro-service
2. Define layers for Voting (REST, Service, Model)
3. Create a Spring boot project for **Worker** Micro-service
4. Define **MQ** communication, from Voting to Worker, with RabbitMQ. Look at [this](https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-amqp/rabbitmq-sendreceive-java-object-messages-spring-rabbitmq-springboot)
5. Define a PostgreSQL Database for **DB**
6. Define layers from Worker to DB (Client, Service, Model, Data),
   using JPA & Hibernate to write in the database
7. Define a simple **Frontend** with Angular
8. Define the communication with Voting
9. Create **Results** with Node.JS
10. Read from database with Results

Each of these steps needs rigourous tests.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it my best!